# Windows Phone 7 "back button" how to detect?

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to detect back button for windows phone 7 so far I have been using BackKeyPress() event, but it did not work? Instead of changing the page (when clicking back button on phone), it goes straight to menu! Why is that?

Code:

```
//BackKeyPress event handler
private void LeaveWindow(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
     this.Content = new MainPage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```